# HyperLink text not rendered after controls are added

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `HyperLink` control with text in its `Text` property.

With the following code:

```
var link = new HyperLink();
var img = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
img.Attributes.Add("src", "text.png");
link.Text = "Test";
link.Controls.Add(img);
```

When I do this, the image is rendered inside a `a` tag, but the text is not rendred.
Is there a way to render both the image and the text inside the `Text` property without throwing a third control in to the mix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put any controls into the `WebControl.Controls` collection, it will ignore what you have inside `Text`. So if you want to render both text and other child controls, you should add the text into `Controls`:

```
var link = new HyperLink();
var img = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
img.Attributes.Add("src", "text.png");
link.Controls.Add(new Literal{ Text = "Test"});    // this line will add the text
link.Controls.Add(img);
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel this should work out for you.

```
var link = new HyperLink();
var img = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
var lbl = new Label();
img.Attributes.Add("src", "text.png");
lbl.Text = "Test";
link.Controls.Add(img);
link.Controls.Add(lbl);
this.Controls.Add(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.imageurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "The HyperLink control can be displayed as text **or** an image." So the answer is no, I'm afraid.